# Best practice for many try-catch blocks

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have many statements that can throw exceptions. Exceptions are not important.

My system accepts missing patient data fields.

```
patientData.PatientId = message.Find(...);
try
{
    patientData.Gender = message.Find(...);
}
catch
{
    // no gender, no problem
}

try
{
    patientData.DateOfBirth = message.Find(...);
}
catch 
{
    // no DateOfBirth, no problem
}
// and many other try-catch blocks ...
```

What is the best way to write these statements that can throw exceptions but not critical?

Comment: What type is `message`? Why does the `Find` method throw if it can't find a match?

Comment: So you're happy to just ignore any old exception, like `NullReferenceException` for example? That doesn't seem like a great plan.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I know it is not a good plan :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you can create static `TryFindMessage` method in addition to `Find`.  In case of exception just return false.
For example:
 `bool Message.TryFind(..., Message message, out string result)`.

But, if you wish some generic approach which you can use with anything, then you can take advantage of delegates and create some static helper.

You can use `Action` or `Func` in that case. Add another extension method which accepts `Func` if you need to return some value from executed function.

```
 public static class SilentRunner
    {
        public static void Run(Action action, Action<Exception> onErrorHandler)
        {
            try
            {
                action();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                onErrorHandler(e);
            }
        }

        public static T Run<T>(Func<T> func, Action<Exception> onErrorHandler)
        {
            try
            {
                return func();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                onErrorHandler(e);
            }

            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

And then use it so:

```
SilentRunner.Run(
     () => DoSomething(someObject),
     ex => DoSomethingElse(someObject, ex));
```

In case of `Func`, you can take result as well:

```
var result = SilentRunner.Run(
     () => DoSomething(someObject),
     ex => DoSomethingElse(someObject, ex));
```

Comment: Which will ignore any kind of exception, and that's bad. Also, in case of `Run<T>` - you have no way of knowing if the function completed and happened to return `default(T)` or if it threw an exception... If you're going to use such a construct, you better think of a better return type (like a value tuple of `bool, T`, for example).

Comment: @ZoharPeled Your propose for `Run<T>` is understandable. I just tried to give him an idea. And regarding to exceptions, sometimes such cases is unavoidable. For example, in a project which has may problems already.  That's why I just answered to the exact question of OP.

Comment: Once you introduce `SilentRunner` in your project, you silently allow other younger developers to use it as simplest way to avoid exceptions :)

Comment: @Fabio Sometimes we are using it. While doing some network call mostly. Adn with the help of Polly we already have some retry mechanism. So, to be honest it is sometimes useful. And regarding to mistakes of young developers we have Code-review.

Comment: You can have such methods only with specific exceptions it will catch, for example `TimoutException`, but having `SilentRunner` which ignore all exceptions is dangerous from application point of view.

Comment: @Fabio Nobody forces us to use it everywhere. To be honest, in our case we are not just returning boolean, but logging exception inside catch block. I just modified it for the OP due to his requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> I have many statements that can throw exceptions. Exceptions are not
>   important.

This can be dangerous, because exceptions can be thrown for different reasons, not only because of missing property.

I would advise instead of swallowing exception, modify code to return default value(`null`) when value is not found.

You can introduce new method in `message` class, for example `FindOrDefault`

```
// Pseudo code
public T FindOrDefault(string property)
{
     return CanFind(property) ? Find(property) : default(T);
}
```

Usage of such method will be self explanatory

```
patientData.PatientId = message.Find(...); // Mandatory - must throw if not found
patientData.Gender = message.FindOrDefault(...);
patientData.DateOfBirth = message.FindOrDefault(...);
```

Comment: @emert117, with accepted approach you will introduce another one ;)

Comment: btw, `null` is default only for reference types, of course. for value types default values are `0` for numerics (including enums), `false` for booleans, `DateTime.MinValue` for `DateTime` etc'.